Question about relationship between algebraic varieties and schemes
Sorry in advance for sloppy notation or assumptions. I'm not at all familiar with scheme theory, I just got started quite recently. I messed around a bit based on my intuition with algebraic varieties and had some question.
Below I forget all data about the sheaf of rings attached to the schemes i.e. I only look at the set, just for simplicity.

Let $k$ be algebraically closed field, and $X/k$ be an affine variety over $k$ with coordinate ring $A(X)$. The corresponding scheme (over $k$) is $\mathrm{Spec}(A(X))$, along with a structure morphism $\mathrm{Spec}(A(X)) \to \mathrm{Spec}(k)$. The correspondence is given by
\begin{align*}
X &\to \mathrm{Spec}(A(X)) \\
P &\mapsto \mathbb{I}(\{P\}) = \mathfrak{m}_P = \{f \in A(X) : f(P) = 0\}
\end{align*}
There is also the reverse map
\begin{align*}
&\psi : \mathrm{Spec}(A(X)) \to X \\
&\psi(\mathfrak{a}) := \mathbb{V}(\mathfrak{a}) = \{P \in X : \forall f \in \mathfrak{a}, f(P) = 0\}
\end{align*}
(And take the unique element out, since $\mathbb{V}(\mathbb{I}(\{P\})) = \{P\}$)
And the structure morphism is induced by the identity map (since $A \to B$ induce $\mathrm{Spec} B \to \mathrm{Spec} A$).
Question 1: Am I correct so far

Next we look at points. Grothendieck said we can represent points by point schemes $\mathrm{Spec}(k) \to \mathrm{Spec}(A(X))$. A point $P \in X/k$ can be mapped to a point scheme $P' \in \mathrm{Spec(A(X))}$ induced from the evaluation map $A(X) \to k$ given by $\mathrm{eval}_P : f \mapsto f(P)$. Chaining this with the map above, we get a map $\mathrm{Spec}(k) \stackrel{\phi}{\to} \mathrm{Spec}(A(X)) \stackrel{\psi}{\to} X$. This means that I start with a point $P \in X$ and end up with a map $\mathrm{Spec}(k) \to X$.
Question 2: Is the image of this map always $P$, or what is going on here?
I tried answering the second question by unravelling all the definitions. The induced map $\phi$ is given by $\phi(\mathfrak{a}) = \mathrm{eval}_P^{-1}(\mathfrak{a}) = \{f \in A(X) : f(P) \in \mathfrak{a}\}$. Chaining this with $\psi$ gives
\begin{align*}
(\phi^*\psi)(\mathfrak{a})
&= \{P \in X : \forall f \in \{g \in A(X) : g(P) \in \mathfrak{a}\}, f(P) = 0\} \\
&= \{P \in X : \forall f \in A(X), f(P) \in \mathfrak{a} \implies f(P) = 0\}
\end{align*}
It seems simple but I can't wrap my head around this. If $\mathfrak{a} = \{0\}$ is the general point, then the expression becomes $\{P \in X : \forall f \in A(X), f(P) = 0\} = \mathbb{V}(A(X)) = X$? But then what happens when $\mathfrak{a}$ is something else.
Hope I'm not missing something stupid...

Part 1 of question 1 is okay, but the second part may be wrong depending on what your conventions for a variety are. If your definition of a variety does not have generic points (i.e. non-closed points whose closures are subvarieties of your original variety), then the reverse map you define will not work. I'd suggest adding your definition of a variety to your post.

@KReiser Thanks for the comment. I think I'm a bit confused myself too, I will go and review some textbooks. Thank you for helping out!

You seem to be on the right track overall. Your Question 1 discussion looks sound.
What i think is the crucial distinction to make so as to clarify things up in your attempt to Question 2 is what kind of "point" you want to talk about.
Let $X$ be a scheme. A priori a point is just an element of the underlying topological space: if $X=Spec(A)$, this amounts to a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p} \in Spec(A)$. A priori, the set $\{\mathfrak{p}\}$ is not necessarily closed.
The correspondence you are alluding to in Question 2 is between points of the naive classical variety and the closed points of the associated scheme. When the zero ideal is prime (i.e. when the ring $A$ is an integral domain) then it does indeed correspond to a point on the scheme, but does not correspond to any one point in the "classical" algebraic variety, (as long as this variety is not just a bunch of disjoint points).
In short, a scheme has just more points than its naive classical brother, because it has weirder points. One prominent example of weird point is the "zero ideal" you mentioned. That one (when it is prime, which i remind you is not always the case) is the furthest from a closed point you can find: in fact its closure is the whole scheme! You discovered this in the computation that led you to your "contradiction" :)
At this stage this should be confusing: to understand why your procedure produces only (and all!) closed points, you can take a look at Gortz-Wedhorn I , in the "Prevarieties as schemes" paragraph of Chapter 3. In particular, look at Corollary 3.36. The key idea to introduce is that of $K-point$: considering such points for various fields $K$ is one very good reason fo which schemes are a interesting.

Thanks for the excellent explanation and resources. I will check them out first and wait a bit before accepting but thanks for the help :)
